# How do you perform Skill Moves?

Tags: fifa-13

When I bought FIFA 13 it didn't come with a game manual. I heard someone talking about skill moves so I researched them, and while I tried doing what I was told me, I didn't get any results. Can someone please tell me how to do skill moves in FIFA 13? Or at least something about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The majority of skill moves in Fifa 13 are performed using a combination of the `L2` (PS3) / `LT` (Xbox 360) and a movement of the right stick.

Whilst holding down `L2` or `LT`, moving the right stick in a direction or a combination of directions will make the player with the ball perform different skills.

The skills that players can do are dependent on their skill-star rating. Every skill has a star rating between 2 and 5. If the player you currently control has a skill-star rating equal or above that, then they can perform that skill.

It is possible that you were trying high star rated skills with a player unable to do them.

This **[here](http://gameguidefaq.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/fifa-13-all-skill-moves-trick-list-ps3.html)** lists the different skills and the skill-star rating that they require.